# Knockout foreach binding with Json Object

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to bind a table using a foreach binding of Knockout. However, my observable properties are reflecting changes, but the data is not able to bind with the table. Below is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <table class="table table-Alternate table-condensed header" id="appTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th style="font-weight: bold;">Market </th>
        <th style="font-weight: bold;">Product Name</th>
        <th style="font-weight: bold;">Company Name</th>
        <th style="font-weight: bold;">Product Id</th>
        <th style="font-weight: bold;">Publisher Name </th>
        <%--<th><span style="font-weight: bold;" id="Span1">Action</span></th>--%>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="appAnnieData" data-bind="foreach: CompanyInfo">
      <%-- <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text:Market"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Product_Name"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Company_Name"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Product_id"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Unified_Product_Name"></span></td>
      </tr>--%>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).on('click', '#appAnnieSearch', function() {
  mainModel = $(this);
  var id = $(this).parents().find("#txtCompanyId").val();
  if (id == "") {
    toastr.info('Please enter Company ID');
    return false;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "../../Services/AService.asmx/GetCompanyInformation",
    data: {
      id: JSON.stringify(id)
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function(res) {
      if (res.d != null && res.d != undefined && res.d != "NotFound") {
        var options = JSON.parse(res.d);

        FillDetailsForCompany(options.app_list);


      } else {
        toastr.options.timeOut = 7000;
        toastr.options.closeButton = true;
        toastr.info('No information found for the selected Company Id. Please try another one.');
      }
      document.getElementById("loader_search").style.display = "none";

    },
    error: function(errormsg) {
      $(".dropdown_SubDomainLoading").hide();
      toastr.options.timeOut = 7000;
      toastr.options.closeButton = true;
      toastr.error('Something Went Wrong');
    }
  });
});

function FillForCompany(appanydata) {
  var dataArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < appanydata.length; i++) {

    dataArray.push(new AppViewModel(appanydata[i].market, appanydata[i].product_name, appanydata[i].company_name, appanydata[i].product_id, appanydata[i].unified_product_name,
      appanydata[i].product_franchise_id, appanydata[i].product_category, appanydata[i].unpublished, appanydata[i].company_id, appanydata[i].unified_product_id, appanydata[i].product_franchise_name, appanydata[i].publisher_id,
      appanydata[i].publisher_name, appanydata[i].product_code));

  }
  DomainModule.dataContext.CompanyInfo(dataArray);
}

function AppViewModel(market, product_name, company_name, product_id, unified_product_name, product_franchise_id, product_category, unpublished, company_id,
  unified_product_id, product_franchise_name, publisher_id, publisher_name, product_code) {
  self = this;
  self.Market = ko.observable(market);
  self.Product_Name = ko.observable(product_name);
  self.Company_Name = ko.observable(company_name);
  self.Product_Id = ko.observable(product_id);
  self.Unified_Product_Name = ko.observable(unified_product_name);
  self.Product_Franchise_Id = ko.observable(product_franchise_id);
  self.Product_Category = ko.observable(product_category);
  self.Unpublished = ko.observable(unpublished);
  self.Company_Id = ko.observable(company_id);
  self.Unified_Product_Id = ko.observable(unified_product_id);
  self.Product_Franchise_Name = ko.observable(product_franchise_name);
  self.Publisher_Id = ko.observable(publisher_id);
  self.Publisher_Name = ko.observable(publisher_name);
  self.Product_Code = ko.observable(product_code);
}
```

The observable property is getting populated and when I inspect the object value **DomainModule.dataContext.CompanyInfo** has the respective data. However, I do not get the table populated.

I am trying to fetch the data on the click event of a button. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What are the `<%--` tags in your HTML?

Comment: I forgot to uncomment it. Its actually the <tr> tag

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are you calling `applyBindings`?

Comment: yes I am calling applyBindings. that is why I am getting data in my observableArray. but foreach not working

Comment: "Any errors in the console?" seconded

Comment: I suggest you add a `<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></span>` just above your table to see what data you really have at that context-level.

Comment: No there are no errors in the console. that is why I got a bit confused as what exactly is the problem. I am fetching data and binding it on the click event.

Comment: As much as your foreach binds to the `CompanyInfo` property, you haven't provided your call to `ko.applyBindings`, so it is impossible to tell if the `CompanyInfo` property is within scope for the binding.